# Converting array of type char into a int variable

Tags: c++

Compiling this on [Codepad](http://codepad.org/vlhwNjBN):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main (void)
{
    char ch[2];
    int value;
    cout<<"Enter two integers between 0-9"<<endl;
    cin.getline(ch,2);

    //testing with char array
    //(...)
    //how could I do operations like '*', '+', '-', or '/' to the char arrays
}
```

Gives:

> Line 4: error: '::main' must return 'int'
>   compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

For example:

Lets say `ch[0]='5'` and `ch[1]='3'`

what do I need to do so I can do ch[0] - ch[1] = 2 and store into an int value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different problems with the code you've posted. `main` needs to have a return type of `int`.

```
int main() { /* .. */ }
```

Your call to [`cin.getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/) will only fill a single character in the array you've declared, because the function call will null terminate the array. You need

```
char array[3];

cin.getline( array, 3 );
```

After that, if `array[0]` contains '5' and `array[1]` contains '3', you can simply do

```
array[0] - array[1]
```

to get the integer result 2.

If you need to deal with numbers outside the range [0..9] you'll need to convert them to their numeric representation. This can be done using [`std::stringtream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/) or [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/).

Comment: Thanks now I see it. I forget the last index location in the array contains a null

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't have to do anything at all in particular. `int x = ch[0] - ch[1]` works quite as you would expect it to.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the original exercise would ask you to get two different integer of probably more than 1 character each.

However, the solution to your problem: ch[0] - ch[1].

Why it works?

Ascii character '0' is character 48.
Ascii character '9' is character 48 + 9

now....

'4' - '3' = (48 + 4) - (48 + 3) = 4 - 3 = 1.

Comment: Ok i got it to work. I was using getline which seemed to give me issue but i used cin.get() and it works like a charm. thanks

Comment: The issue also is 48 using ASCII. If I multiple or add the value is totally off from what it is suppose to be.

Comment: Then you can do (ch[0] - '0') * (ch[1] - '0') for example